# How to boot Arch Linux on MSI B250M PRO-VDH?

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, grub2, efi

I want to achieve a proper GRUB installation, so it will be able to EFI boot Arch Linux on my MSI B250M PRO-VDH without further user intervention.

Everything has been set-up as it follows:

**/dev/sdc1 is the EFI Partition, FAT32 400 MB, mounted to /boot (/mnt/boot outside of chroot)**

**/dev/sdc2 is swap, 16 GB**

**/dev/sdc3 is the Linux partition in which Arch has been installed, EXT4 around 100 GB, mounted to / (/mnt outside of chroot)**

Everything goes fine until the bootloader installation. Through arch-chroot I installed grub and efibootmgr, then proceeded installing, as always:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=BOOT
```

No errors reported, then made the configuration file, as always:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

No errors reported. Once I rebooted my system, the boot entry wasn't there at all.

I proceeded copying **grubx64.efi** to **bootx64.efi** and the boot entry finally appeared, though it always boots up to the GRUB shell instead of loading Arch Linux. Rebuilding the configuration file doesn't work either.

Plugging the drive on another EFI system successfully boots Arch Linux up without further hassles.